# How to make JVM use the max (all remain) memory of a server

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, jvm

I have an DFS algorithm java console application, that runs faster when more memory is provided. Just a DFS algorithm application, with neither I/O nor other outer-JVM resource usage. It consumes only CPU and memory. The application can run with an 1GB memory, but run much more faster with 2 GB memory. More memory provided, faster the application can run. I haven't touch the speed limit as 12GB of memory provided. So I must use all remain memory of a server to speed it up. And the application need not parallel, one request only at one time.

And I need to install the application on different server with different memory size.

Is there a way to let JVM use the all remain memory of the server?

```
-XX:MaxRAMFraction=1
```

MaxRAMFraction is not EVERY server good, some server will result in start JVM failure as location memory failure, some works good.

Use an wrapper application get system remain memory, and minus some memory usage other than Xmx, then start the real application with same Xms and Xms. The method will also result in JVM memory allocation error. Because the code below returns much more than memory we can use, not just a minus of Xss256m or some more non-heap JVM memory.

```
com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean mbean = (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean)
    ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
long size = mbean.getFreePhysicalMemorySize();
```

So is there a good way to let JVM use all remain memory of a server?

Comment: Write a script that works on your operating system to find out the remaining memory, then start Java with -Xmx and the amount of remaining memory. Note: this can be dangerous, because memory needs at point X in time can be very different from point Y in time.  What you want makes it very dependent on when you start the VM (during your nightly batch jobs or not?) - it's better to go from the perspective of the amount of memory you *need* rather than what's available.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt it's not nightly batch job, just a DFS algorithm application, with neither I/O nor other outer-JVM resource. The application can run with an 1GB memory, but run much more faster with 2 GB memory, the more memory provided faster the application can run. So why not use the all remain memory of a server?

Comment: If you're never running anything else on the server and the memory use of the server is always the same over time, then sure, no problem. But then you can also determine this once by hand and figure out which `-Xmx` argument you want to pass to Java.

Comment: @Erwin once by hand :(  It would be a terrible thing that I need to install the application on dozens of different servers with different memory size. And I am not very certain if the free memory will change after some server/os maintenance.

Comment: As I suggested in my first comment you can write a script that determines it before you start Java. In any case you need to know before you start Java, you can't change it after the VM has started.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt As I mentioned in the last part of topic. I tried a wrapped program to get remaining memory, and then start the JVM with same Xms and Xmx (only setting Xmx for an memory hungry application is not good enough). The result is that, I cannot find a clear (or linear) relation between the remain memory and Xms/Xmx setting. The  `OperatingSystemMXBean` Result often returns something like 4.6G, but we can start the JVM with only 3.1G or so. And the worse is, this gap is server specified. And it's quite bigger gap than I think just some Xss and non-heap usage.

Answer (score 2):

For large regions of memory I use off heap and this reduces overhead on the GC, one of the benefitis is that is can be any size at runtime and even larger than main memory if you do it carefully.  You can use direct `ByteBuffer`s but I use a library I wrote which extends the ByteBuffer functionality (>> 2 GB and thread safe) [Chronicle Bytes](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Bytes) The largest any one uses this is ~100 TB of virtual memory mapped to disk.

We have two data structures on top of Chronicle Bytes, a key-value store [Chronicle Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map) and a queue/journal [Chronicle Queue](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue). This can make storing data off heap easier with a higher level interface.

The way the heap works, it has to reserve the maximum heap size on start up as a single continuous block of virtual memory.  In particular, the GC assumes random access to this memory on a clean up which means if you are have slightly over utilised your memory, possibly because a process started after yours and some of the heap is swapped out you will see a dramatic fall in performance for your whole machine. Windows tends to start swapping your GUI meaning you can't get back control without a power cycle. Linux isn't as bad, but you will want to kill your process at this point. This makes tuning it size to use all memory very hard if the usage of your machine changes.

By using virtual memory by comparison, the GC doesn't touch it so unused portions have little impact. You can have areas of virtual memory many times main memory but only your current working set matters, and this is a size entirely in your control at runtime. Note: on Linux you can have virtual memory sizes 1000x your free disk space, but use with care, if you run out by touching too many pages your program will crash.

Comment: Nice solution. To apply it the OP needs to have control over the source code and the bandwidth to adapt to your library but depending on his use case that could be worth the effort.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt if he doesn't want to use my library he can use multiple ByteBuffers though that would be more work I suspect.

Comment: Yes, off heap usage is a great and correct idea. And I'm also considering working on it (or just switch to another language with better memory management? lol). But the old application has plenty of object types need remain in memory, it will be much pain to rewrite it to use off heap just with bytes. So, can we just focus on some methods not change the code too much?

Comment: @rufushuang the simplest solution is to add more memory of course. I wouldn't recommend using off heap until your data/heap is already around 32 GB.  My 8 year old has an old computer which I didn't use for 2 years and it has 24 GB, my TV has 16 GB.  If you need 1+ TB, self managed virtual memory is your only answer in any language.